# How can I get the frequencies of common itemsets from the apriori call in R?

Tags: r, associations, apriori

**Problem:**

The [apriori](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/arules/html/apriori.html) function of the [arules](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html) package infers association rules from the input transactions and reports the *support*, *confidence*, and *lift* of each rule. The association rules are derived from frequent itemsets. I'd like to get the most frequent itemsets in the input transactions. Specifically, I'd like to get all itemsets with a given minimum support. The support of an itemset is the ratio of the number of the transactions that contain the itemset to the total number of transactions.

**Requirements:**

1. I'd strongly prefer to find the most frequent itemsets from the intermediate results of the [apriori](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/arules/html/apriori.html) function. That is, I'd rather not to write a program from scratch just to compute the most frequent itemsets, because the [apriori](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/arules/html/apriori.html) function already computes it as an intermediate step. Nonetheless, if there is really not a reasonable way of accessing the intermediate results of the [apriori](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/arules/html/apriori.html) function, I'm open to other solutions.
2. I'd rather not to do string manipulation on the result of the [apriori](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/arules/html/apriori.html) function because this approach will be too dependent on the string representation of the result of the [apriori](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/arules/html/apriori.html) function. Again, if it turns out that there are no better alternatives, I may resort to this approach.
3. I'm aware of the `itemFrequency` function provided by the [arules](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html) package. Unfortunately, this function just reports the itemsets with a single item. I'm interested in all itemsets of any length with a minimum support.
4. I'd like the output to be sorted by support numerically and then by itemset lexicographically.

**Example Input:**

```
a,b
a,b,c
```

**Program:**

```
# The following is how I'm using apriori to infer the association rules.
library(package = "arules")
transactions = read.transactions(file = file("stdin"), format = "basket", sep = ",")
rules = apriori(transactions, parameter = list(minlen=1, sup = 0.001, conf = 0.001))
WRITE(rules, file = "", sep = ",", quote = TRUE, col.names = NA)
```

**Current Output:**

```
"","rules","support","confidence","lift"
"1","{} => {c}",0.5,0.5,1
"2","{} => {b}",1,1,1
"3","{} => {a}",1,1,1
"4","{c} => {b}",0.5,1,1
"5","{b} => {c}",0.5,0.5,1
"6","{c} => {a}",0.5,1,1
"7","{a} => {c}",0.5,0.5,1
"8","{b} => {a}",1,1,1
"9","{a} => {b}",1,1,1
"10","{b,c} => {a}",0.5,1,1
"11","{a,c} => {b}",0.5,1,1
"12","{a,b} => {c}",0.5,0.5,1
```

**Desired Output:**

```
"itemset","support"
"{a}",1
"{a,b}",1
"{b}",1
"{a,b,c}",0.5
"{a,c}",0.5
"{b,c}",0.5
"{c}",0.5
```

Comment: (Reposting from R chat) I'm not sure, but it looks like you could do some regular expressions to get the text part.  The rest looks like it's the first element in the numeric vector.

Comment: @Iterator I've found a way to access the intermediate results of the `apriori` function call: `generatingItemsets`. See my partial solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the `generatingItemsets` function in the reference [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/arules.pdf) of the arules package.

```
library(package = "arules")
transactions = read.transactions(file = file("stdin"), format = "basket", sep = ",")
rules = apriori(transactions, parameter = list(minlen=1, sup = 0.001, conf = 0.001))
itemsets <- unique(generatingItemsets(rules))
itemsets.df <- as(itemsets, "data.frame")
frequentItemsets <- itemsets.df[with(itemsets.df, order(-support,items)),]
names(frequentItemsets)[1] <- "itemset"
write.table(frequentItemsets, file = "", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
```